# Running program in Xamarin.Android causing Unhandled Exception in creating button handlers

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I was making a sample android app to test things out and the error is as follows on creating a button handler, though my build succeeded.

[Screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XU5C.png)

Please help

Error: Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred

PLease help me with an appropriate solution:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Android_Picture
{
[Activity(Label = "Android Picture", MainLauncher = true, Icon = 
"@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Button ButtonPrev;
    Button ButtonNext;
    TextView TextTitle;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
         SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        ButtonPrev = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonPrev);
        ButtonNext = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonNext);
        TextTitle = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textTitle);

        ButtonPrev.Click += ButtonPrev_Click; //error
        ButtonNext.Click += ButtonNext_Click;
    }

    private void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TextTitle.Text = "Next Clicked";
        //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void ButtonPrev_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TextTitle.Text = "Previous Clicked";
        //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

My Main.axml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:text="Prev"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonPrev"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
<Button
    android:text="Next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
<TextView
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is ButtonPrev null?  Are you sure the FindViewById call that assigns it's value succeeded?

Comment: yeah.. my build succeeded !! @Jason

Comment: It may be a Layout issue i guess..? Cz.. I changed from Linear to Relative one !

Comment: the fact that your build is successful is irrelevant.  Null Reference errors are runtime errors, not build errors.

Comment: What should I do to reference the object then... Suggest me ? @jason

Comment: you need to learn how to use the debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
```

Is very important, it is what actually sets the layout for your Activity. If you don't have this `FindViewById` will always return null.

Either inflate a proper view or create one.

Comment: he is right, you are not telling android which layout to use

Comment: No i already have it... I did not mention it here though @Cheesebaron. Well yes I changed from a Linear Layout to a Relative Layout.

Comment: I have mentioned the Main layout code... the error is the same... I am not notified during the build... but at runtime

Comment: You need to actually call `SetContentView`. In the code you have provided, it is commented out `//`.

Comment: Thanks I uncommented it.. but I am still there... Unsolved! @jason